# Improving query for more efficient writing

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

[image: Diagram]

How would you improve the following query in SQL Server to find in which of the courses the men/women ratio is over 70%? (I added a diagram of all tables related..not all of them are necessary)

```
SELECT 
    F.CourseId, 
    CAST(ROUND(CAST(M.Men AS FLOAT) / CAST(F.Women AS FLOAT) * 100, 2) AS NUMERIC(12, 2)) AS Ratio
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         c.CourseId, COUNT(DISTINCT c.StudentId) AS Women
     FROM 
         Classrooms c
     INNER JOIN 
         Students s ON c.StudentId = s.StudentId
     WHERE 
         s.Gender = 'F'
     GROUP BY 
         c.CourseId) F
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         c.CourseId, COUNT(DISTINCT c.StudentId) AS Men
     FROM 
         Classrooms c
     INNER JOIN 
         Students s ON c.StudentId = s.StudentId
     WHERE  
         s.Gender = 'M'
     GROUP BY 
         c.CourseId) M ON F.CourseId = M.CourseId
WHERE 
    CAST(M.Men AS FLOAT) / CAST(F.Women AS FLOAT) * 100 > 70
ORDER BY 
    F.CourseId
```

I want to practice effective and shorter (better) queries.

Thank you all!

[image: Table Examples]

Comment: Why are you converting your `COUNT`s to a `float`?

Comment: Please provide tables structure and sample data as SQL statements. [mre]

Comment: You can count men, women conditionally in a single run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use single query like:

```
SELECT 
     c.CourseId, 
     COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.Gender = 'F' THEN c.StudentId ELSE NULL END) AS Women,
     COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.Gender = 'M' THEN c.StudentId ELSE NULL END) AS Man,
     CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.Gender = 'M' THEN c.StudentId ELSE NULL END) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(DISTINCT c.StudentId) AS MensRate
FROM Classrooms c
INNER JOIN Students s ON c.StudentId = s.StudentId
GROUP BY c.CourseId
HAVING CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.Gender = 'M' THEN c.StudentId ELSE NULL END) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(DISTINCT c.StudentId) > 0.7
```

[MS SQL fiddle group by](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=023eddfe46e58323573cd162072f7eda&php_version=null&sql_version=mssql2019)

A mean you should to divide Men's count to total count for rate calculate.

Comment: I added AS FLOAT so I won't miss a result due to round.
Thank you!